# Why does this jQuery ajax call lose the 'data' setting?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following script to get a list of files given a path:

```
function getFiles(dirPath) {
    $("#fileList").empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Get", "File")',
        data: dirPath,
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .done(function (files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            $("#fileList").append('<li>' + files[i] + '</li>');
        };
    });
};
```

where `fileList` is an empty `ul`. This calls into the following action method:

```
public IActionResult Get(string dirPath)
{
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
    var files = dirInfo.GetFiles();
    var ret = new List<string>();
    foreach (var info in files)
    {
        ret.Add(info.Name);
    }
    return Json(ret);
}
```

When the script `getFiles` method is called, `dirPath` has a valid path to a directory, and I expect when I set the `data` option to this path, it will get appended to the eventual URL used for the call.

Yet when my `Get` action method is called, its `dirPath` parameter value is `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need to see what the value of `dirPath` is. If it's an object with a key of `dirPath` it should work fine, eg. `{ dirPath: '/foo/bar/' }`. A querytring will work too. If it's a plain string, eg. `'/foo/bar'`, it won't work.

Comment: Pass data like this `data: {dirPath: dirPath},`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `dirPath` like below:-

```
data: {dirPath : dirPath},
```

Note:-

You can pass either a queryString in URL or a data object through `GET` method. So either add your `dirPath` directly into `url` parameter as a queryString or make it as an object and pass (as given in above code)

Comment: @ProfK ha ha ha . It happens with every-one. In my case it happens frequently :):)